# Cmake error when I try install Opencv 3.1 on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-15.10, opencv3.1

I want to compile and install OpenCV 3.1 on my Ubuntu 15.10. I follow the this tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html#gsc.tab=0

After I run the cmake command, the installation begin, but the process return error, and ALL FILES IN MY UBUNTU TURN IT TO READ-ONLY (wft????). Here is the output log: http://pastebin.com/vJz0U7es

I dont understand very well cmake. Can Somebody help me?

Comment: I think you need to install ffmpeg.

Comment: I installed, but the error to be continued.